# How to do you get a footer to stick to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, footer

I require my footer to stick to the bottom of the page. Currently sticks to the bottom when the view port is full and doesn't extend. However when I use a smaller resolution I get a vertical scroll bar, and the footer remains where the view port was originally and doesn't stick to the bottom of the page.

Link: http://cazdesigns.net/caz/pictures.html

Any help would be appreciated. I have tried multiple techniques which only seem to work in the view port and not when vertically scrolling is involved.

Comment: what techniques you tried, can we see only the 1st one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `position:fixed;` add the following to your CSS:

`#footer{position:fixed;}`

Answer (score 0):

Just merege this css code with your css:-

```
html { min-height:100%; float:left;} 
body { min-height:100%; float:left; position:relative;}
#footer { position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; width:100%; padding-top:25px;}
```

And remove Postion:relative from #gallery div...